# How to prevent image in fluid container displayed cropped

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please take a look of the following code and result.

**html:**

```
<div id="social_media">
    <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="facebook.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="gplus.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="linkedin.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#social_media {
    width:70%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.social{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.social li{
    width: 14%;
    margin: 0 5.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**result:**

[image]

Is it possible to keep this fluid layout, but prevent images displayed like that. You'll notice that the bottom edges of the images is displayed as if it's cropped. The second and third images get cropped on the right side too.

**UPDATE:**
Please take a look of the live example
http://jsfiddle.net/ktsixit/bcceC/embedded/result/
The list is placed in a fluid container ad I think that's the key to this isuue/solution.

**SOLUTION:**
This turn to be a firefox issue. Any suggestions about how to fix that are welcomed...

Comment: give your `img` a `width: 100%; height: auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.social{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.social li{
    width: 14%;
    margin: 0 5.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.social li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I believe you need to tell your images to fit the width of their parent. As at the moment the image appears too large for it's parent container, therefore cannot be shown fully. This should fix your issue and ensure that the images will fit the container when going down to smaller screens etc.

Comment: Yes, looks more promising than my example. Maybe some `overflow: visible;` on the `<li>` to make sure it get not cutted off?

Comment: No need to over complicate it, `width: 100%;` will make the image fit it's parent, and then `height: auto;` will determine the correct height that is in proportion to the width. This ensures that it always fits it's parent's size.

Comment: please take a look of the fiddle I posted. It seems that the reason of this is that the list is contained in a fuid container too.

Comment: I can see no problem on your fiddle, what's the issue?

Comment: By the way, as a tip, i would suggest using SVG instead of images for icons :)

Comment: It seems that this is a browser spesific issue. Firefox is displayed the images like this. They look ok in Chrome. I guess that there's nothing we can do about it...

Comment: you'll find loads of annoying browser quirks unfortunately, if my answer has helped you please accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is simply how images get scaled down by browsers. Did you make sure that your image files are not broken or something?

Anyway, there is an experimental specification called `image-rendering` which only works in the latest browser version except IE. I can't recommend using this, but want to keep this option open for you.

```
img[src$=".gif"], img[src$=".png"] {
   image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
   image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
   image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
   image-rendering: crisp-edges;
   -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

Read a more detailed text here: [image-rendering on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

Comment: While this is true, this looks more to be that the image is larger than it's container so is being cut off

Comment: @morkro I tried your suggested solution. The images are displayed without being cropped indeed but they also look pixelated. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Did you try `crisp-edges`? Because this makes them pixelated. You could also give them the property `optimizeQuality`.